# How to treat collection of data objects as a database table?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to find a way to treat Java data object collection as a database table.

**For example:**
There is an array list of student data object scanned from Excel sheet. Now I want an easy way to list down :

•   Students born in the same months
or
•   Students from computer class
or
•   Students having the same street address
or
•   Students whose last name are XYZ

To achieve this, I don't want to loop through the list for every requirement. 
I am looking for something like it that works in DB, just query for what you need and it returns you the requested information.

Comment: why not actually dump the data into a database?

Comment: You might try something like the H2 database which can run inside the JVM: http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html, but there are lots of other options.

Comment: @blahfunk : Don't want to create database dependency.  Just want to get my inputs in excel sheet or CSV file, process it and display the information. No persistence is required.

Comment: @guitarsteve : thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it and update you soon.